# How to upload large files directly to S3 via Rails in a AngularJS App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my project I have a requirement to allow users to upload very large files (up to 4GB) to S3.

My current setup includes Rails 4.2, S3, Paperclip, Mongoid for the API and AngularJS (with [this](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) upload library) for the front-end. Currently I can upload regular sized (up to 20MB) files perfectly fine.

So, I need to allow the front-end app users to upload zip files from an Angular JS app, through a Rails API to S3.

There is no need for file processing on the server, so all the serve needs to do with the file is keep track of its url (the location on S3) and file name so these details can be referenced later on.

After some search I've found [this tutorial](http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and) and [this gem](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) that suggest uploading the files directly to S3 bypassing the app altogether.

In my Angular controller I have this code to upload small sized files:

```
$scope.submitItem = function(file, file2, file3) {
  Upload.upload({
      url: API_PROVIDER.full_path + 'instant_downloads.json',
      data: {file: file, data: $scope.instant_download, categories: $scope.instant_download.categories, avatar: file2, 
        subcategories: $scope.subcategories, zipfile: file3, options: $scope.instant_download.options}
  }).then(function (result) {
    if (result.data.success) {
      $scope.showAlert('Instant Download created successfully', 'success');
      $state.go('app.instant_downloads.index');
    }
  }, function (result) {
      angular.forEach(result.message, function(value, key){
        $scope.showAlert(_.capitalize(key) + ': ' + value.join(', '), 'danger');
      });
  }, function (evt) {
    $scope.progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
  });
};
```

And the above code works well. If I try the above code on a large file I get a `nginx` timeout errors.

Then I tried to use aforementioned gem (while still using the same AngularJS code) to bypass the server but I get an error on the S3 side (it seems it also timeout.

Can someone point me out how I can upload directly to S3, using the AngularJS controller above with a callback to the server so I can get the confirmation the file has been uploaded successfully along with its url?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad as we don't know what you've tried or why those didn't work. We also don't know your expertise level, so answers would have to take a broad swipe at answering, or would result in tutorials themselves, which is off-topic.